# How can I add and remove files from an ISO image with Delphi?

Tags: archiving, iso-image, delphi

Are there any (preferably free) Delphi components or libraries that handle ISO files?

In particular, I would like to be able to add files and save to ISO, as well as extract the files from an ISO.

I do not require advanced features or bells and whistles, just something to do what I mentioned above.

I tried to find some but came up with nothing really.

Perhaps this can be done without the need of such a library? If so what approach would you recommend?

Comment: @Andreas I dont know how this got here, I posted it over at the Stack Overflow site, somebody moved it here. This was a DELPHI question so who ever moved it should not have, I dont have the requirements to move it back or delete it.

Comment: Agree with Andreas Rejbrand. Also, [archiving] whaat? Disregard that sillypaedia says, ISO9660 images are not archives. Proper term which unites disk images with archives is **compound file**.

Comment: The question has been re-opened at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking for something like **FreeBurner** (http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeburner/)

> *"**Open Source** CD / DVD Burning library
>   for **Delphi**, Includes the ISO9660
>   library to **create ISO images**, also the
>   Audio library to help burn audio CDs,
>   this library does not require any
>   other software to work."*

Comment: thanks I will check that out, never heard of FreeBurner before and it is OpenSource.

Comment: Tried it, but it seems this component is not compatible with Delphi XE. I managed to get past all the Unicode errors and installed the package successfully but there are too many runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

[7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) looks like it can handle ISO files in the same way as other archives. I has no problem to extract the files, however I did not try to add files to ISO and burn it.

Comment: This question should not be here, I posted it as a Delphi Programming releated question. I know all about 7Zip, WinRar, UltraISO etc..

Comment: oops, sorry for that oversight, I currently have to work on small netbook, where I see only a small part of the website, so I overlooked the tags... sorry again

Comment: thats ok, i know how your eyes can go all boggly looking on them things :)